# Matlab - Find indices of nearest non-zero element for every zero matrix element

Tags: matlab, matrix, nearest-neighbor

In Matlab, I have a matrix, where some elements are set to zero. E.g:

```
0 1 0 0 0
2 5 0 3 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 5 0 2 1
```

For every matrix element which is zero I want to find the indices of the nearest element which is not zero. When multiple indices are possible, all of them should be returned. What could be a clever solution here, how can I avoid a lot of for-loop stuff?

Comment: `diff` may be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by nearest? Vertically, horizontally, diagonally?

Comment: @dean_sh: All directions you listed should be considered.

Comment: Does diagonal count as 1.414 or 2?

Comment: Curious, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar: Accepted Amro's answer because of its simplicity but I like your answer too. It's always useful to learn how to implement something like that from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an efficient [`bwdist` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) in IPT that computes the [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform):

```
M = [
    0 1 0 0 0
    2 5 0 3 0
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 5 0 2 1
];
[D,IDX] = bwdist(M~=0)
```

The result:

```
D =
    1.0000         0    1.0000    1.0000    1.4142
         0         0    1.0000         0    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.4142    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000         0    1.0000         0         0

IDX =
           2           5           5          14          14
           2           6           6          14          14
           2           6           6          14          20
           8           8           8          16          20
```

The returned `IDX` contains **linear indices** of nearest nonzero value in `M`. It only return one index per element.

Comment: Distance Transform is the #1 way to go for this... especially since there are very efficient implementations of it that aren't brute-force. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) that stores indices of non-zero nearest elements (by euclidean distance) for each zero element in a cell each -

```
%// Assuming A as the input matrix. Store rows, columns of zero and non-zeros
[rz,cz] = find(A==0);
[rnz,cnz] = find(A~=0);

%// Store zero pt indices
zero_pts = [rz cz];

%// Get squared euclidean distances
dists = bsxfun(@minus,rnz,rz.').^2 + bsxfun(@minus,cnz,cz.').^2;

%// Get all nearest XY indices of nonzeros for each zero pt
[R_idx,C_idx] = find(bsxfun(@eq,min(dists,[],1),dists));
idx = [rnz(R_idx) cnz(R_idx)];

%// Cut at each shifting positions and thus create a cell array, with a
%// cell of indices of non-zero nearest elements for each zero element 
nearest_nnonzero_pts = mat2cell(idx,histc(C_idx,1:max(C_idx)))
```

Sample input, output -

Input :

```
>> A
A =
     0     1     0     0     0
     2     5     0     3     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     5     0     2     1
```

Output (Zero points) :

```
>> disp(zero_pts)
     1     1
     3     1
     4     1
     3     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
     4     3
     1     4
     3     4
     1     5
     2     5
     3     5
```

Output (Corresponding nearest non-zero points) :

```
>> celldisp(nearest_nnonzero_pts)
nearest_nnonzero_pts{1} =
     2     1
     1     2
nearest_nnonzero_pts{2} =
     2     1
nearest_nnonzero_pts{3} =
     4     2
nearest_nnonzero_pts{4} =
     2     2
     4     2
nearest_nnonzero_pts{5} =
     1     2
nearest_nnonzero_pts{6} =
     2     2
     2     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{7} =
     2     2
     4     2
     2     4
     4     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{8} =
     4     2
     4     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{9} =
     2     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{10} =
     2     4
     4     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{11} =
     2     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{12} =
     2     4
nearest_nnonzero_pts{13} =
     4     5
```